# VueJS Tailwind Contain div within itself without impacting others

Tags: html, css, laravel, vue.js, tailwind-css

So, I am going ABSOLUTELY crazy here. I have attached a pic showing the issue. It is as follows:

- The layout on the right is a user list
- The middle content for chat should be y-scroll
- The bottom div should be locked in place and not move.

For some reason, the way it works now the scroll is all over the place and I feel like I should be doing this a lot better. It just feels "off" to me. I am normally a backend guy and I am struggling with this badly and I don't know how best to resolve this.

I have attached my code for assistance please and thank you!!

[image: Look at the vertical scroll position to see the issue - the bottom div is hiding the content]

```
<div class="w-full">
   <div class="sm:hidden">
      <label for="tabs" class="sr-only">Select a tab</label>
      <select id="tabs" name="tabs" class="block w-full  focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 border-gray-300 dark:border-gray-600">
         <option>Room 1</option>
         <option>Room 2</option>
         <option>Room 3</option>
         <option>Room 4</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="hidden sm:block sticky top-0 z-10">
      <div class="border-b border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-600">
         <nav class="-mb-px flex bg-white dark:bg-gray-900" aria-label="Tabs"><a href="#" class="bg-indigo-800 text-gray-50 w-1/4 py-4 px-1 text-center border-b-2 dark:text-gray-50  dark:border-gray-600 font-medium text-sm" aria-current="page">Room 1</a><a href="#" class="text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700 hover:border-indigo-300 w-1/4 py-4 px-1 text-center border-b-2 dark:text-gray-50  dark:border-gray-600 font-medium text-sm">Room 2</a><a href="#" class="text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700 hover:border-indigo-300 w-1/4 py-4 px-1 text-center border-b-2 dark:text-gray-50  dark:border-gray-600 font-medium text-sm">Room 3</a><a href="#" class="text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700 hover:border-indigo-300 w-1/4 py-4 px-1 text-center border-b-2 dark:text-gray-50  dark:border-gray-600 font-medium text-sm">Room 4</a></nav>
      </div>
   </div>
   <section class="h-full w-full flex-1 flex scrollbar-thin hover:scrollbar-thumb-indigo-700 dark:hover:scrollbar-thumb-indigo-700 dark:scrollbar-thumb-gray-600 dark:scrollbar-track-gray-800 scrollbar-thumb-gray-400 scrollbar-track-gray-50 overflow-y-scroll">
      <ul class="divide-y dark:divide-gray-700 divide-dotted divide-gray-200 w-full">
         <li class="bg-gray-300 py-2 px-3">
            <div class="flex space-x-3">
               <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
               <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200">1h</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">test</p>
                     <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">public</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="bg-gray-300 py-2 px-3">
            <div class="flex space-x-3">
               <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
               <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200">1h</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">test</p>
                     <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">public</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="bg-gray-300 py-2 px-3">
            <div class="flex space-x-3">
               <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
               <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200">1h</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">test</p>
                     <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">public</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="bg-gray-300 py-2 px-3">
            <div class="flex space-x-3">
               <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
               <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200">1h</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">test</p>
                     <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">public</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="bg-gray-300 py-2 px-3">
            <div class="flex space-x-3">
               <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
               <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200">1h</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">test</p>
                     <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">public</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="bg-gray-300 py-2 px-3">
            <div class="flex space-x-3">
               <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
               <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200">1h</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">test</p>
                     <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">public</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="bg-gray-300 py-2 px-3">
            <div class="flex space-x-3">
               <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
               <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200">1h</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">test</p>
                     <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">public</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="bg-gray-300 py-2 px-3">
            <div class="flex space-x-3">
               <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
               <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200">1h</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">test</p>
                     <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">public</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="bg-gray-300 py-2 px-3">
            <div class="flex space-x-3">
               <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
               <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200">1h</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">test</p>
                     <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">public</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="bg-gray-300 py-2 px-3">
            <div class="flex space-x-3">
               <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
               <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200">1h</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">test</p>
                     <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">public</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="bg-gray-300 py-2 px-3">
            <div class="flex space-x-3">
               <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
               <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200">1h</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">test</p>
                     <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">public</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="bg-gray-300 py-2 px-3">
            <div class="flex space-x-3">
               <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
               <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200">1h</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">test</p>
                     <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">public</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="bg-gray-300 py-2 px-3">
            <div class="flex space-x-3">
               <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
               <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200">1h</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">test</p>
                     <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">public</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="bg-gray-300 py-2 px-3">
            <div class="flex space-x-3">
               <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
               <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200">1h</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">test</p>
                     <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">public</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="bg-gray-300 py-2 px-3">
            <div class="flex space-x-3">
               <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
               <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200">1h</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">test</p>
                     <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">public</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="bg-gray-300 py-2 px-3">
            <div class="flex space-x-3">
               <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
               <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200">1h</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">test</p>
                     <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">public</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="bg-gray-300 py-2 px-3">
            <div class="flex space-x-3">
               <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
               <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200">1h</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">test</p>
                     <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">public</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="bg-gray-300 py-2 px-3">
            <div class="flex space-x-3">
               <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
               <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200">1h</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">test</p>
                     <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">public</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="bg-gray-300 py-2 px-3">
            <div class="flex space-x-3">
               <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
               <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200">1h</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">test</p>
                     <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">public</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="bg-gray-300 py-2 px-3">
            <div class="flex space-x-3">
               <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
               <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200">1h</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">test</p>
                     <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">public</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="bg-gray-300 py-2 px-3">
            <div class="flex space-x-3">
               <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
               <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200">1h</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                     <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">test</p>
                     <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">public</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </section>
   <section aria-labelledby="chat-footer" class="h-auto w-full sticky shadow-2xl bg-gradient-to-br from-gray-100 to-gray-300 dark:from-gray-900 dark:to-gray-900 border-l dark:border-gray-800 border-gray-200 bottom-0 min-w-full flex-1 flex flex-col lg:order-last">
      <div>
         <span class="pl-10 pt-2 relative z-0 inline-flex shadow-sm rounded-md">
            <button type="button" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-3 py-1 rounded-l-md border border-gray-300 bg-white dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
               <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M10 20l4-16m4 4l4 4-4 4M6 16l-4-4 4-4"></path>
               </svg>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-3 py-1 border border-gray-300 bg-white dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
               <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 4a4 4 0 100 8 4 4 0 000-8zM2 8a6 6 0 1110.89 3.476l4.817 4.817a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414l-4.816-4.816A6 6 0 012 8z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
               </svg>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-3 py-1 border border-gray-300 bg-white dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
               <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 16v1a3 3 0 003 3h10a3 3 0 003-3v-1m-4-8l-4-4m0 0L8 8m4-4v12"></path>
               </svg>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-3 py-1 border border-gray-300 bg-white dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
               <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M8 11V7a4 4 0 118 0m-4 8v2m-6 4h12a2 2 0 002-2v-6a2 2 0 00-2-2H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v6a2 2 0 002 2z"></path>
               </svg>
            </button>
            <div class="relative inline-block text-left">
               <div>
                  <button id="headlessui-menu-button-1" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 rounded-r-md border border-gray-300 bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-700 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-50 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                     Send Option 
                     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" class="-mr-1 ml-2 h-5 w-5">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                     </svg>
                  </button>
               </div>
               <!---->
            </div>
         </span>
         <div class="pr-10 pl-10 pb-5  h-full mt-1 flex rounded-md shadow-sm">
            <div class="relative flex items-stretch flex-grow focus-within:z-10">
               <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 pl-3 flex items-center pointer-events-none">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400">
                     <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 4.354a4 4 0 110 5.292M15 21H3v-1a6 6 0 0112 0v1zm0 0h6v-1a6 6 0 00-9-5.197M13 7a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0z"></path>
                  </svg>
               </div>
               <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full rounded-none rounded-l-md pl-10 sm:text-sm border-gray-300" placeholder="Type your message...">
            </div>
            <button id="switchTheme" class="-ml-px bg-indigo-700 relative inline-flex items-center space-x-2 px-4 py-1 border border-gray-300 dark:border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-r-md text-gray-700 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
               <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="h-5 w-5 text-gray-50">
                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M10.325 4.317c.426-1.756 2.924-1.756 3.35 0a1.724 1.724 0 002.573 1.066c1.543-.94 3.31.826 2.37 2.37a1.724 1.724 0 001.065 2.572c1.756.426 1.756 2.924 0 3.35a1.724 1.724 0 00-1.066 2.573c.94 1.543-.826 3.31-2.37 2.37a1.724 1.724 0 00-2.572 1.065c-.426 1.756-2.924 1.756-3.35 0a1.724 1.724 0 00-2.573-1.066c-1.543.94-3.31-.826-2.37-2.37a1.724 1.724 0 00-1.065-2.572c-1.756-.426-1.756-2.924 0-3.35a1.724 1.724 0 001.066-2.573c-.94-1.543.826-3.31 2.37-2.37.996.608 2.296.07 2.572-1.065z"></path>
                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 12a3 3 0 11-6 0 3 3 0 016 0z"></path>
               </svg>
               <span class="text-gray-50">Send</span>
            </button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </section>
</div>
```

Comment: The code seems to be incomplete? It just appears to have the scrolling section with 21 (identical?) `li` items. It might help if you can produce a minimal example which reproduces the problem.

Comment: @ShauntheSheep I was fighting with it and still am. I am trying to create a minimal view but thought I would start with this in case someone saw the issue. Basically its 2 divs on top of each other and the top div needs to scroll and the bottom div can't - what is happening is the top div is behind the bottom div so content gets lost. I am working on it though!

Comment: OK, but as far as I can see, the code you've posted probably doesn't contain the parts you have a problem with :), as far as I can see. It just seems to be the chat section without the other `div`s you mention.

Comment: @ShauntheSheep lets try that edit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to make the outer div flex column (`flex-col`), and then set max height (`max-h-screen`)..

```
<div class="w-full flex flex-col max-h-screen">
   <div class="sm:hidden">
   </div>
   <section class="w-full flex scrollbar-thin hover:scrollbar-thumb-indigo-700 dark:hover:scrollbar-thumb-indigo-700 dark:scrollbar-thumb-gray-600 dark:scrollbar-track-gray-800 scrollbar-thumb-gray-400 scrollbar-track-gray-50 overflow-y-scroll">
   </section>
   <section aria-labelledby="chat-footer" class="h-auto w-full sticky shadow-2xl bg-gradient-to-br from-gray-100 to-gray-300 dark:from-gray-900 dark:to-gray-900 border-l dark:border-gray-800 border-gray-200 bottom-0 min-w-full flex-1 flex flex-col lg:order-last">
   </section>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/7GfwHdfCjS)